# Recursive CTE query looping until conditions are met

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I'm trying to write a query where it will recursively seek to find inception or the part number has changed.

There is a single table `stktrans` that holds the **IN** and the **OUT** transactions of any orders.

When something is sent **OUT** it will have an **IN_Nr** which can be used to trace back the the **IN** transaction. The **OrderNr** links the **IN** to the **OUT**

EDIT: Given any IN_Nr I'd like to be able to trace back to the original order it was purchase on. In the table below - TransID 1. But showing the full timeline of the events like the table below.

| TransID | Part | IN_Nr | OUT_Nr | OrderNr | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 123-1 | 232753 | 232233 | 888777 | OUT |
| 7 | 123-1 | 232753 | NULL | 125707 | IN |
| 6 | 123-1 | 203944 | 224789 | 125707 | OUT |
| 5 | 123-1 | 203944 | NULL | 123332 | IN |
| 4 | 123-1 | 179409 | 198306 | 123332 | OUT |
| 3 | 123-1 | 179409 | NULL | 111222 | IN |
| 2 | 123-1 | 176573 | 171516 | 111222 | OUT |
| 1 | 123-1 | 176573 | NULL | 666000 | IN |

The patter between the tracing back is as in the picture below:

[image: Illustration]

Currently, I have a very un-dynamic query which can trace back 4 levels from any given **IN_Nr**:

```
    DECLARE @IN_Nr INT = 232753
    
    
    ;WITH StkOUT_CTE AS (
            SELECT 
                ST.TransID, 
                ST.Part, 
                ST.IN_Nr, 
                ST.OUT_Nr,
                ST.OrderNr, 
                ST.Type
            FROM 
                StkTrans ST 
            WHERE
                OUT_Nr IS NOT NULL
                AND ST.Type = 'OUT'
    ),
    StkIN_CTE AS (
            SELECT 
                ST.TransID, 
                ST.Part, 
                ST.IN_Nr, 
                ST.OUT_Nr,
                ST.OrderNr, 
                ST.Type
            FROM 
                StkTrans ST 
                INNER JOIN StkOUT_CTE SI ON SI.IN_Nr = ST.IN_Nr
            WHERE
                ST.Type = 'IN'
    )
    SELECT 
           *
      FROM 
      (
              SELECT 
                1 RowOrder, *
              FROM 
              StkOUT_CTE  
              WHERE IN_Nr = @IN_Nr
          UNION
              SELECT 
                2 RowOrder, *
              FROM 
              StkIN_CTE
              WHERE IN_Nr = @IN_Nr
          UNION
            SELECT 3 RowOrder, *
            FROM 
                StkOUT_CTE
            WHERE
                OrderNr = (SELECT OrderNr FROM StkIN_CTE WHERE IN_Nr = @IN_Nr)
          UNION
            SELECT 4 RowOrder, *
            FROM 
                StkIN_CTE
            WHERE
                IN_Nr = (
                    SELECT IN_Nr
                    FROM 
                        StkOUT_CTE
                    WHERE
                        OrderNr = (SELECT OrderNr FROM StkIN_CTE WHERE IN_Nr = @IN_Nr))
        ) ST
```

To Create a similar setup:

```
    CREATE TABLE StkTrans (
        TransID INT, 
        Part VARCHAR(25), 
        IN_Nr INT, 
        OUT_Nr INT, 
        OrderNr INT, 
        Type    VARCHAR(3)
    )

    INSERT INTO StkTrans
    (TransID, Part, IN_Nr, OUT_Nr, OrderNr, Type)
    VALUES
    (1, '123-1', 176573, NULL, 666000, 'IN' ),
    (2, '123-1', 176573, 171516, 111222, 'OUT' ),
    (3, '123-1', 179409, NULL, 111222, 'IN' ),
    (4, '123-1', 179409, 198306, 123332, 'OUT' ),
    (5, '123-1', 203944, NULL, 123332, 'IN' ),
    (6, '123-1', 203944, 224789, 125707, 'OUT' ),
    (7, '123-1', 232753, NULL, 125707, 'IN' ),
    (8, '123-1', 232753, 232233, 888777, 'OUT' )
```

Any guidance that might point me in the right direction on how to use the CTE recursively would be great!

Comment: Side note, what you have above are *not* recursive CTEs. A Recursive CTE has a `UNION ALL` in it, and references itself in bottom `SELECT`. For the sample data you've given us, what are the results you are expecting here?

Comment: @Larnu Thanks, yes I'm not sure how to write the query but I think a "real" Recursive CTE would potentially work. I'm trying to create a query that given any IN_Nr can track back to the origin on what it was purchase in on. e.g. TransID 1

Comment: @MaciejLos thanks for that but it always start a IN_Nr which is give and from there you have to work back to get to TransID 1 - e.g. if you are supplied IN_Nr = 203944 - your query wouldn't work would it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading between the lines, perhaps this is what you want?

```sql
WITH rCTE AS(
    SELECT *,
           1 AS Iteration
    FROM dbo.StkTrans ST
    WHERE ST.IN_Nr = '232753'
      AND ST.[Type] = 'IN'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT STi.*,
           r.Iteration + 1
    FROM dbo.StkTrans STo
         JOIN dbo.StkTrans STi ON STo.IN_Nr = STi.IN_Nr                     
         JOIN rCTE r ON STo.OrderNr = r.OrderNr
    WHERE STo.[Type] = 'Out'
      AND STi.[Type] = 'In')
SELECT TOP (1) TransID
FROM rCTE
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Iteration DESC);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1b42fd88e7990b7d06cabb507b412e52)

---

Edit:
Perhaps this is what you are therefore after. I now parametrise the first dataset in the rCTE as well, for ease of testing against other values.

```sql
DECLARE @IN_Nr int = 232753;

WITH rCTE AS(
    SELECT V.*,
           1 AS Iteration
    FROM dbo.StkTrans STo
         JOIN dbo.StkTrans STi ON STo.IN_Nr = STi.IN_Nr      
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(STo.TransID,STo.Part,STo.IN_Nr,STo.OUT_Nr,STo.OrderNr,STo.[Type]),
                            (STi.TransID,STi.Part,STi.IN_Nr,STi.OUT_Nr,STi.OrderNr,STi.[Type]))V(TransID,Part,IN_Nr,OUT_Nr,OrderNr,[Type])
    WHERE STo.IN_Nr = @IN_Nr
      AND STo.[Type] = 'OUT'
      AND STi.[Type] = 'In'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT V.*,
           r.Iteration + 1
    FROM dbo.StkTrans STo
         JOIN dbo.StkTrans STi ON STo.IN_Nr = STi.IN_Nr                     
         JOIN rCTE r ON STo.OrderNr = r.OrderNr
                    AND r.[Type] = 'In'
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES(STo.TransID,STo.Part,STo.IN_Nr,STo.OUT_Nr,STo.OrderNr,STo.[Type]),
                            (STi.TransID,STi.Part,STi.IN_Nr,STi.OUT_Nr,STi.OrderNr,STi.[Type]))V(TransID,Part,IN_Nr,OUT_Nr,OrderNr,[Type])
    WHERE STo.[Type] = 'Out'
      AND STi.[Type] = 'In')
SELECT TransID,
       Part,
       IN_Nr,
       OUT_Nr,
       OrderNr,
       [Type]
FROM rCTE
ORDER BY TransID DESC;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f9bf6c35fe60dd3ae3fc593382e86b38)

Comment: Seems that OP wants to "trace back". See "EDIT" part.

Comment: That's what the above does, @MaciejLos . It gives the value `1` for `TransID`; unfortunately I didn't get the expected data I asked for so I had to guess a little. Not sure what you mean above I'm afraid.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear the expected result would show the full timeline of the transactions until we reach the beginning.

Comment: Then just remove the `TOP (1)` and change the columns in the final `SELECT`, @Justin . Also, you'll likely therefore want to change the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: If you put the *actual* expected results in your question [I asked for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68080790/recursive-cte-query-looping-until-conditions-are-met/68081143#comment120329455_68080790), @Justin , I'll be happy to amend.

Comment: @Larnu the expected results would be the table in the question which shows the timeline of the part by the IN_Nr.

Comment: But that's also your sample data, @Justin . You could get *that* data with a simple `SELECT * FROM dbo.StkTrans;'`

Comment: @Larnu I didn't want to show other data to clutter - but you're right. But the IN_Nr could start from any of the numbers in the table e.g. IN_Nr starting at 203944 would show TransIDs from 6 to 1. By tracing back through the IN_Nr and OrderNr.

Comment: I have added a second solution for you, @Justin .

Comment: @Larnu wow this looks really good - how does it work with the Cross Apply? I'd like to learn if you can point me in the right direction

Comment: I'm using `CROSS APPLY` to "unpivot" the data @Justin . Due to joining the data from the "In" and "Out" rows, they end up on *one* row. I therefore use a `VALUES` table construct to turn them back into 2 separate rows.